# SQL: Summarize rows by column value, without using UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to write an sql statement which summarizes the count of rows by values in a specific column.

I have several tables, starting with s0_
Every table has a huge amount of rows with multiple, different values in column load_nr.

Example:
s0_table1:

| load_nr | column2 | column3... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | someData | someData... |
| 101 | someData | someData... |
| 102 | someData | someData... |
| 103 | someData | someData... |
| 103 | someData | someData... |
| 103 | someData | someData... |

S0_table2:

| load_nr | column2 | column3... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | someData | someData... |
| 102 | someData | someData... |
| 102 | someData | someData... |
| 102 | someData | someData... |
| 102 | someData | someData... |
| 103 | someData | someData... |

Desired result:

| load_nr | count s0_table1 | count s0_table2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2 | 1 |
| 102 | 1 | 4 |
| 103 | 3 | 1 |

New data with up counting load_nr is added every day.
Best case is, that the table names are fetched dynamically (s0_*).

Could anyone give me a cloue how to build this statement? I'm a newbe and not so experienced with more complicated statements.

Best Regards

*edit: Hopefully the tables are displayed correctly xD

Answer (score 0):

For that you need a FULL OUTER JOIN in case the load_nr don't match up

```
SELECT COALESCE(s1.load_nr,s2.load_nr) as load_nr, Count_S1, Count_S2
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) Count_S1,load_nr FROM S0_table1 GROUP BY load_nr) s1 FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) Count_S2,load_nr FROM S0_table2 GROUP BY load_nr) s2  ON s1.load_nr = s2.load_nr
```

ORDER BY load_nr

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic table names are going to be a problem.  You basically have no choice but to write a SQL statement dynamically.  There's a good chance that summing a UNION-ed subquery is going to be the fastest way to go, but if you can also try this:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(
        Table1Count.[load_nr],
        Table2Count.[load_nr],
        Table3Count.[load_nr]       
    ) [load_nr],
    COALESCE(Table1Count.[rows],0) [s0_table1],
    COALESCE(Table2Count.[rows],0) [s0_table2],
    COALESCE(Table3Count.[rows],0) [s0_table3]
FROM            (   SELECT  
                        [load_nr],
                        COUNT(1) [rows]
                    FROM        s0_table1
                    GROUP BY    [load_nr]
                ) Table1Count
FULL OUTER JOIN (   SELECT  
                        [load_nr],
                        COUNT(1) [rows]
                    FROM        s0_table2
                    GROUP BY    [load_nr]
                ) Table2Count
ON              Table2Count.load_nr = Table1Count.load_nr
FULL OUTER JOIN (   SELECT  
                        [load_nr],
                        COUNT(1) [rows]
                    FROM        s0_table3
                    GROUP BY    [load_nr]
                ) Table3Count
ON              COALESCE(
                    Table1Count.[load_nr],
                    Table2Count.[load_nr]       
                ) = Table3Count.load_nr
```

Of course you'd need to build the query dynamically and the nested coalesces for each subsequent join could get a bit tricky.

Another option if you have the load numbers you need in another table you can make it cleaner and easier to construct dynamically:

```
SELECT 
    loads.[load_nr],
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table1 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table1Count],
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table2 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table2Count],
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table3 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table3Count],
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table4 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table4Count]
FROM    loads
```

And if you need to remove the loads with no rows in any table you can just wrap it in a subquery and add a where clause:

```
SELECT 
    SubQuery.*
FROM    (   SELECT 
                loads.[load_nr],
                (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table1 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table1Count],
                (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table2 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table2Count],
                (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table3 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table3Count],
                (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table4 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table4Count]
            FROM    loads
        ) SubQuery
WHERE   (       SubQuery.[s0_table1Count] <> 0
            OR  SubQuery.[s0_table2Count] <> 0
            OR  SubQuery.[s0_table3Count] <> 0
            OR  SubQuery.[s0_table4Count] <> 0
        )
```

This could be pretty slow though depending on the shape of your data.

Comment: Indeed there is a table with a colum load_nr.
But when I'm executing this query:
`SELECT 
    loads.[load_nr],
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table1 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table1Count],
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table2 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table2Count],
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table3 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table3Count],
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM s0_table4 WHERE load_nr = loads.[load_nr]) [s0_table4Count]
FROM    loads`


im getting this error:
`SQL-Fehler [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
Error position: line: 2 pos: 19`

Comment: Postgres probably doesn't like my [TableName].[ColumnName] syntax.  I do M$ SQL Server.  Try just removing the square brackets.  They're not necessary if the column name has no space anyway.  I think maybe postgres uses single quotes, but that's a really dusty decade-old half memory so don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if any of the following will work for you. This is something that
I haven't ever used in a real project, but maybe it will provide you with some
inspiration. The final solution will get 99% to having the best case that you
wanted (more on this at the end).

Here's the basic idea. `psql` provides a command called `\crosstabview` that is
able to display pivot tables, which is what you want. So, for your sample data,
we could do this (notice that instead of terminating the query with a semicolon
`;`, we're terminating it with `\crosstabview`):

```sql
select load_nr, 's0_table1', count(*) from s0_table1 group by load_nr
union
select load_nr, 's0_table2', count(*) from s0_table2 group by load_nr
order by load_nr asc

\crosstabview
```

```
┌─────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ load_nr │ s0_table1 │ s0_table2 │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│     101 │         2 │         1 │
│     102 │         1 │         4 │
│     103 │         3 │         1 │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Try the same query with a semicolon terminator to see what the query has returned
before `psql` post-processed the result:

```sql
select load_nr, 's0_table1', count(*) from s0_table1 group by load_nr
union
select load_nr, 's0_table2', count(*) from s0_table2 group by load_nr
order by load_nr asc
```

```
┌─────────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ load_nr │ ?column?  │ count │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────┤
│     101 │ s0_table1 │     2 │
│     101 │ s0_table2 │     1 │
│     102 │ s0_table1 │     1 │
│     102 │ s0_table2 │     4 │
│     103 │ s0_table2 │     1 │
│     103 │ s0_table1 │     3 │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────┘
```

Ok. Now this was a `psql` thing, but it PostgreSQL provides a built-in
extension called `tablefunc` which exposes a function called `crosstab` that
does precisely what the psql `\crosstabview` command does. Furthermore, this
function accepts as argument a *string* containing the SQL text of the query
you need, which means we could generate it.

For the moment we can just use the hardcoded query (I'm using `$$`-delimited
strings below so that I don't have to escape single quotes):

```sql
create extension if not exists tablefunc;

select * from crosstab(
  -- The 1st argument is the query producing the values on the two dimentions:
  -- `load_nr` and table name.
  $$
  select load_nr, 's0_table1', count(*) from s0_table1 group by load_nr
  union
  select load_nr, 's0_table2', count(*) from s0_table2 group by load_nr
  order by load_nr asc
  $$,

  -- The 2nd argument must return the headers names, which in our case are
  -- the table names
  $$
  select * from (values ('s0_table1'), ('s0_table2')) as headers
  $$
) as (
  "load_nr" int,
  "count s0_table1" int,
  "count s0_table2" int
);
```

The above will return this, which reproduces perfectly the `\crosstabview`
result:

```
┌─────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ load_nr │ count s0_table1 │ count s0_table2 │
├─────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│     101 │               2 │               1 │
│     102 │               1 │               4 │
│     103 │               3 │               1 │
└─────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Ok, now on to dynamically generate the two SQL queries that `crosstab` wants.

First, we can obtain a list of the table names prefixed with `s0_`:

```
select
  relname
from
  pg_catalog.pg_class
where relname like 's0_%'
order by relname asc;
```

```
┌───────────┐
│  relname  │
├───────────┤
│ s0_table1 │
│ s0_table2 │
└───────────┘
```

Now, we can use these values to build individual `SELECT` statements that we'll
later join via `UNION`. First the `SELECT`s:

```sql
select
  'SELECT load_nr, ''' || relname || ''', count(*) FROM ' || relname || ' GROUP BY load_nr' as sql_text
from
  pg_catalog.pg_class
where relname like 's0_%'
order by relname asc;
```

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                               sql_text                                │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ SELECT load_nr, 's0_table1', count(*) FROM s0_table1 GROUP BY load_nr │
│ SELECT load_nr, 's0_table2', count(*) FROM s0_table2 GROUP BY load_nr │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Now we can join the 2 rows into a single one:

```
select string_agg(sql_text, E'\nUNION\n') || E'\nORDER BY load_nr ASC' from (
  select
    'SELECT load_nr, ''' || relname || ''', count(*) FROM ' || relname || ' GROUP BY load_nr' as sql_text
  from
    pg_catalog.pg_class
  where relname like 's0_%'
  order by relname asc
) as queries;
```

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                               ?column?                                │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ SELECT load_nr, 's0_table1', count(*) FROM s0_table1 GROUP BY load_nr↵│
│ UNION                                                                ↵│
│ SELECT load_nr, 's0_table2', count(*) FROM s0_table2 GROUP BY load_nr↵│
│ ORDER BY load_nr ASC                                                  │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

If we take this query and manually run it using `\crosstabview`, we'll get:

```sql
SELECT load_nr, 's0_table1', count(*) FROM s0_table1 GROUP BY load_nr
UNION
SELECT load_nr, 's0_table2', count(*) FROM s0_table2 GROUP BY load_nr
ORDER BY load_nr ASC \crosstabview
```

```
┌─────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ load_nr │ s0_table1 │ s0_table2 │
├─────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│     101 │         2 │         1 │
│     102 │         1 │         4 │
│     103 │         3 │         1 │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Nice, so this was precisely what we wanted. We can now use SQL-generating query
as the first argument to the function `crosstab`:

```sql
with
  source_sql as (
    select string_agg(sql_text, E'\nUNION\n') || E'\nORDER BY load_nr ASC' from (
      select
        'SELECT load_nr, ''' || relname || ''', count(*) FROM ' || relname || ' GROUP BY load_nr' as sql_text
      from
        pg_catalog.pg_class
      where relname like 's0_%'
      order by relname asc
    ) as queries
  )
  select * from crosstab(
    -- The 1st argument is the query producing the values on the two dimentions:
    -- `load_nr` and table name.
    (select * from source_sql),

    -- The 2nd argument must return the headers names, which in our case are
    -- the table names
    $$
    select * from (values ('s0_table1'), ('s0_table2')) as headers
    $$
  ) as (
    "load_nr" int,
    "count s0_table1" int,
    "count s0_table2" int
  );
```

Executing it will get us:

```
┌─────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ load_nr │ count s0_table1 │ count s0_table2 │
├─────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│     101 │               2 │               1 │
│     102 │               1 │               4 │
│     103 │               3 │               1 │
└─────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Now, the final thing is to replace the 2nd argument to `crosstab` with a proper
query — a way to fetch all table names prefixed with `s0_`, which we already
know how to do — and with that the solution is complete:

```sql
with
  source_sql as (
    select string_agg(sql_text, E'\nUNION\n') || E'\nORDER BY load_nr ASC' from (
      select
        'SELECT load_nr, ''' || relname || ''', count(*) FROM ' || relname || ' GROUP BY load_nr' as sql_text
      from
        pg_catalog.pg_class
      where relname like 's0_%'
      order by relname asc
    ) as queries
  )

  -- select * from source_sql;

  select * from public.crosstab(
    (select * from source_sql),
    $$
      select relname from pg_catalog.pg_class
      where relname like 's0_%'
      order by relname asc
    $$
  ) as (
    load_nr int,
    "count s0_table1" int,
    "count s0_table2" int
  );
```

Coming back to my observation that this will bring you just 99% to your ideal
solution. The reason for that is the fact that `crosstab` requires a column
list definition, this part, where you have to manually list the table headers
(again):

```sql
  ) as (
    load_nr int,
    "count s0_table1" int,
    "count s0_table2" int
  );
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to get rid of that last hurdle. And as I
mentioned in the beginning, this query might perform quite badly, but maybe it
is *good enough* for your use case.